# Smart pointers cannot be used as raw pointers automatically?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, implicit-conversion, language-design

I'm trying to convert codes to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.  But was wondering - is it really not possible for smart pointers to be used as raw pointers?

In this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

void printer(int* x)
{
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{   
    auto x = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    printer(x);
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error:

```
In function 'int main()': 14:14: error: cannot convert
'std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >' to 'int*' for argument '1'
to 'void printer(int*)'
```

How should this be coded?  Thanks!

Comment: You need `printer(x.get());` to access the raw pointer behind. That's not done automatically for good reasons.

Comment: See [Herb Sutter on the subject](https://herbsutter.com/2012/06/21/reader-qa-why-dont-modern-smart-pointers-implicitly-convert-to/).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It isn't done implicitly for extremely subjective reasons: "raw" ptr are "unsafe". There is no inherent problem with allowing them. And saying that it's too dangerous to allow conversion to a ptr when you keep using ptr is fundamentally contradicting.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez "_if implicit conversion to * were allowed, would silently compile -- urk_" Saying that implicit conversions allow more programs to compile is trivially true, and not a convince argument at all.

Comment: @curiousguy Smart pointers are all about ownership semantics, and the wrapped pointer is a second class citizen in this regard. The best you could expect instead of `get()` would be an implicit conversion to `std::weak_ptr<T>`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The whole point of using a smart ptr is to access its "second class citizen", lol.

Comment: @curiousguy You missed _"... in a controlled way"_ ;)

Comment: @curiousguy implicit conversion are the root of many painful bugs. Any kind of ownership transfer must never be implicit and passing a pointer may be an ownership transfer. Given that point of view and the fact that the code is written only once, the added 6 char is a small cost.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez The 6 char of `.get()` won't transfer ownership either. In my experience implicit conversions are fine.

Comment: @curiousguy the goal is exactly that: you should not transfert it implicitly. Whenever I have to type `.get()`, I know I have to be careful. In my experience, implicit conversions are rare and used only when really needed (with duck typing by exemple), not for syntactic sugar. When even make constructor with one parameter explicit to avoid instantiating an object by mistake. Without that, impact analysis would be much harder.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez "_implicit conversions are rare_" You mean user defined implicit conversions are rare, don't you?

Comment: @curiousguy yes, I mean user defined conversions. Fortunately, the compilers have good warning support for dangerous conversion in the language (or support for risky ones such as the std::string constructor taking a bool in parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot be an implicit conversion because an implicit conversion doesn't have context to do the right thing. `printer` takes a non-owning pointer, but what about other functions that need to take ownership? For instance

```
void kill(int *p) { delete p; }
```

Silently doing the conversion when calling `kill(p);` would be the wrong thing! It will lead to a double delete. The pointer has no way to know it should stop owning the object, it has to be told via a call to `release`. Anything else would be wrong.

Since smart pointers are all about enforcing explicit ownership semantics, the conversion to a raw pointer needs to be explicit too, and have a name that conveys how the ownership is affected.

Comment: Obviously transfert of ownership needs to be explicit (except by move copy from a rvalue).

Comment: You should mention `get()` and `release()` for the standard pointer types.

Comment: @curiousguy That was a typo, I meant `get()`

Answer (score 0):

`std::make_unique<>()` returns a `std::unique_ptr`, which makes variable `x` of type `std::unique_ptr<int>`. These smart pointers are not just raw pointers and you cannot use them just like raw pointers. You should instead use the `get()` method on `x` to get the `int*` it is pointing to.

Comment: That would be an argument against even having implicit conversion in the language.